# Is there a way to close a modal bottom sheet in flutter that contains a listview?

Tags: flutter, listview

So basically I've been trying for a couple of days to allow users to close a modal bottom sheet when they get to the top of the ListView, when swiping on the ListView. However, when they swipe on the list view the widgets register as if I'm just trying to scroll up on the ListView. Is there a physics type for the ListView to close a modal bottom sheet when at the top or a different way to set up an ignore pointer for this?
This is what I've come up with and I hope I explained myself well enough that this problem is understood.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class ModalSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ModalSheetState createState() => _ModalSheetState();
}

ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
bool close = false;

class _ModalSheetState extends State<ModalSheet> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels < 1) {
        if (_scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
            ScrollDirection.forward) {
          setState(() {
            close = true;
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            close = false;
          });
        }
      } else {
        setState(() {
          close = false;
        });
      }
      print(_scrollController.position.pixels);
      print(_scrollController.position.userScrollDirection);
      print(close);
      // print(close);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Flexible(
            child: IgnorePointer(
              ignoring: close,
              child: ListView.builder(
                controller: _scrollController,
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text('tile: ${index + 1}'),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT: Thanks to @LearningJS888 for the package suggestion below to use this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet)! much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you elaborate what exactly you're trying to do?
A normal way of closing ModalBottomSheet is by `Navigator.pop(context)`.

Comment: I'd like to be able to close the ModalBottomSheet by swiping down on the ListView, but only when the ListView is at the top. Think similar to like a social media app where the bottom sheet pops up and brings you to a webpage and when you finish scrolling to the top of a web page if you continue swiping down you are now controlling the sheet instead of the scrollable widget inside. I hope this is more clear

Comment: Ah I understand, try this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet)